# How to find two orthogonal vectors $a$ and $b$ such that $a$ is the projection of vector U on V and $a+b=U$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, vectors, projective-geometry

> Given that U=<2,6> and V=<9,2> find two orthogonal vectors  $a$ and $b$ such that $a$ is the projection of vector U on V and $a+b=U$

I first wanted to know how to even do this problem and understand it.

- I don't understand the "orthogonal vectors" part, I was wondering if this was referring to the legs the are formed when you project two vectors?
- If not how does one get two orthogonal vectors out of this problem?
- And also assuming that it is the legs, then I must do $Proj_{v}{u}$ right? And if I do that then I only get one vector, then what do I do? And also if this is the case, then is the fact that $a+b=U $ now useless?

Comment: If $U$ is given and you have figured out $a$ and you want $a+b=U$, then it should not be too hard to work out $b$.....

Comment: Orthogonal is a fancy vector word for perpendicular.

Comment: The picture here is that you have two vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ (and $\mathbf{u}$ is shorter than $\mathbf{v}$).The projection of $\mathbf{u}$ onto $\mathbf{v}$ comes from treating $\mathbf{v}$ as the base of a triangle, with the hypotenuse being $\mathbf{u}$ and dropping a line perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}$ from the tip of the vector $\mathbf{u}$ for the height of the triangle. The vector from $\langle 0, 0 \rangle$ to the point where the perpendicular meets $\mathbf{v}$ is the projection - call that vector $\mathbf{a}$. Then $\mathbf{b}$ is just the height of the triangle.

Comment: (In other words, $\mathbf{b}$ is the perpendicular we dropped from the top of $\mathbf{u}$ onto $\mathbf{v}$, expressed as a vector - and we get a right triangle with sides $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{u}$.)

Answer (score 0):

- $a$ and $b$ orthogonal means that $\langle a, b \rangle =0$
- $a$ is the projection of $U$ on $V$ gives that $a=\lambda V$

Then $\langle b, V \rangle=0$ and $\langle U, V \rangle=\langle a, V \rangle$. Then $\lambda \Vert V \Vert ^2 = \langle U, V \rangle = 30$. This gives $\lambda = \frac{6}{17}$.

Then $a=(\frac{54}{17}, \frac{12}{17})$ and $b=U-a=(\frac{-20}{17},\frac{90}{17})$